# Link a Drupal 7 site with a Facebook account

Tags: 7, feeds, social-network

I would like to know if there is a Facebook App that can automatically post content from the feed generated by a Drupal 7 site to one's Facebook Wall.
I would like something that does what My Blog Posts Facebook App promises to do but more efficiently (since that works only by manually refreshing the state).

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb).

A quote from the project page: `If you already have content in Drupal, you can expose it on Facebook.`

Documentation can be found on http://drupal.org/node/195035

Answer (score 1):

Even an easier method could be using the RSS feed of your website and the Notes application in your Facebook page. Notes can publish RSS feed items automaticly.

Comment: looks like Facebook removed that feature

Answer (score 1):

Try the [RSS Graffiti](http://www.facebook.com/RSS.Graffiti) application in facebook.